# Cannot access my session in react js with axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios, express-session

## MY frontend code

```
 axios
.get
("http://localhost:3001/login",
      {
        withCredentials: true ,
        headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }}).then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      });
```

//This console log nothing but empty string
but when I use thunder client to send the login post request and after that login get request I get the result as true which not true for react front end

#MY serer code

```
app.get('/login',(req,res)=>{
    
        res.send(req.session.isAuth);
})


app.post('/login',
(req,res)=>{
    
    let name=req.body.name;
    let password=req.body.password;
    db.query('select first_name,password from user_data where first_name=?',[name],(err,result)=>{
            if(result.length>0){
                if(result[0].password===password){
                     req.session.isAuth=true;
                     req.session.save();
                res.send(
                {isAuth:true,
                 message:'Success'
                })
                }
                else{
                    
                res.send(
                    {
                     isAuth:false,
                     message:'Password incorrect'
                    }
                    );
                }
            }
            else{
                res.send(
                {
                    isAuth:false,
                    message:'User not found'

                })
                
            }
    })
}
)
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: You can go to your Network tab in your browser and see whether or not the request is sent, or see its response.

Comment: the response tab says no response data available

Comment: when i send a request with thunder client i get the result i expect but that doesnot happen with axios